# MongoDB - Get only those documents that matched with an array of ids

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am facing a problem with the `Mongoose` schema collection which has a nested array of objects. The collection name is `Sprint` which contains `tasks` as a sub-document i.e an array of objects.

The schema is something like this.

```
// document 1
{
    _id: ObjectId("6138e5866b19971ba8a60851"),
    tasks: [
        {
            _id: ObjectId("6138e5ad6b19971ba8a60852"),
            taskName: "Hello"
        },
        {
            _id: ObjectId("6138e5ad6b19971ba8a543252"),
            taskName: "Hello 2"
        }
    ]
},
// document 2
{
    _id: ObjectId("6138e5866b19971ba8a76851"),
    tasks: [
        {
            _id: ObjectId("6138e5ad6f19971ba8a60852"),
            taskName: "World"
        },
        {
            _id: ObjectId("6138e5ad6sd19971ba8a543252"),
            taskName: "World 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

My goal was to get only those `tasks` objects in an array that matched with the given `ids`.

My `taskIds` array is something like this.

```
const taskIds = ["6138e5ad6b19971ba8a60852", "6138e5ad6b19971b568a60852"];
```

and I am using the `$in` comparison operator to get these tasks.

```
const query =  {"tasks._id": {$in: taskIds}};
const tasks = await Sprint.find(query);
console.log(tasks);
```

But the data which I am getting is an array of whole documents with its `tasks` in an array of objects. I still don't know how to get only those tasks in an array that matched with the `ids`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood correctly you can use this query:

- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array.
- `$match` by your criteria.
- `$group` using `null` as `_id` because yo want to get all `tasks` values.
- And (optional) `$project` to not show the `_id`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$tasks"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "tasks._id": {
        "$in": [
          "6138e5ad6b19971ba8a60852",
          "6138e5ad6b19971b568a60852"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "tasks": {
        "$push": "$tasks"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5Q33ppQOTSL)

Also, to explain why using you query mongo shows the entire object is because with that query you are telling mongo "five me the documents where the `_id` field in `tasks` array is in this array". And mongo get the entire object where the criteria is done.

Comment: thank you for your great information. But after getting aggregate results how can I use these to remove the collection.

Comment: One last question During aggeration result, How we can attach the `_id` of the parent document in which this embedded document result is matched?

Comment: To remove the elements, if I've not missundersttod you, you can use `$pull` in an `update` query [like this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eW7qKpdMyn3). And to match with parent you can use an extra step `$match` like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9tz5emK7gao)